# Rails - Two or more dots in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app where a route is defined as

```
get "/:username", to: "profiles#show", as: :show_profile, constraints: UsernameConstraints.new
```

And `UsernameConstraints` is defined as

```
class UsernameConstraints
  #Some code
  def matches?(request)
    request.path.match?(/.*/) 
  end
  #Some code
end
```

So that usernames can be something like `myapp.com/user.name`

How do I change this code to accept usernames with two or more dots (`myapp.com/something.like.this`)?
At the moment I can't get rid of the `No route matches` error.

I tried adding `format: true`  to the route and re-building the username in the controller using the parameters:

```
myapp.com/something.like.this 

{"username"=>"something", "format"=>"like.this"}

params[:username] = "#{params[:username]}.#{params[:format]}"
```

But it’s not a clean solution and also the route does not match any more simple usernames like `/username`

Comment: Is there a need to use dots? Seems like this should be parameterize (something-like-this)

Answer (score 0):

```
get "/:username", to: "profiles#show", 
                  as: :show_profile, 
                  username: /[^\/]+/
```

```
Started GET "/foo.bar.baz" for ::1 at 2021-01-25 01:19:18 +0100
Processing by ProfilesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"username"=>"foo.bar.baz"}
Hello World!
Completed 204 No Content in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 45)
```